# Erro ao enviar parâmetro para um servidor PHP usando AJAX (Sem Jquery)

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Olá, estou tentando passar um simples parâmetro para um server em PHP utilizando AJAX e não estou conseguindo pegar esse parâmetro no PHP. O erro retornado é que o index "parametro" do método GET não está definido. Segue abaixo os códigos

função AJAX :

```
function AJAX(){
                var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xmlhttp.open('POST','./functions/adicionafoto.php', true);
                var data = "parametro=OK"
                xmlhttp.send(data);
                xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
                if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4){
                    if(xmlhttp.status == 200){
                        console.log(xmlhttp.responseText)

                    }
                }
                };
            }
```

código do servidor PHP :

```
<?php
    session_start();

    $parametro = $_GET['parametro'];

    echo $parametro;
?>
```

Erro retornado: Undefined index: parametro

Alguém tem idéia do por que isso está acontecendo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primeira coisa: você está fazendo uma requisição do tipo POST e tentando receber do tipo GET.

```
xmlhttp.open('POST','./functions/adicionafoto.php', true);
$parametro = $_GET['parametro'];
```

Altere para `$parametro = $_POST['parametro'];`

Segunda coisa: adicione esse cabeçario

```
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
```

Seu código irá ficar assim:

```
function AJAX() {
     var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
     var data = "parametro=OK"
     xmlhttp.open('POST', './functions/adicionafoto.php');
     xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
     xmlhttp.send(data);
     xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {
           if (xmlhttp.status == 200) {
              console.log(xmlhttp.responseText)

           }
        }
     };


  }

  AJAX()
```

Se tu quiser ao invés de usar o XMLHttpRequest, poderá usar o FetchApi. Seu código ficará assim:

```
const fetchApi = async () => {

     const options = {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
        body: "parametro=OK"
     }

     try {
        const response = await fetch('./functions/adicionafoto.php', options)
        const result = await response.text()
        console.log(result)
     } catch (err) {
        console.error(err)
     }

  }

fetchApi()
```

Comment: Funcionou, obrigado!